# Unexpected result in JavaScript by a 2D Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I create a 2D Array in JavaScript and try to assign one specific object it changes all. Here is my Code:

```
var a = [0,1];
var b = [];
b.push(a);
b.push(a);
b[0][0]=5;
alert(b[1][0]);
```

Now I expect to get `0` but I get `5`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You push the same object reference. by chaging one value, all references shows the changed value. Instead, you could spush a copy of the array by taking [`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

```js
var a = [0, 1];
var b = [];

b.push(a.slice());
b.push(a.slice());

b[0][0] = 5;

console.log(b[1][0]);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

you're pushing array which is reference so value at both the index refer to `a` ( reference to a ) which is why change at any index will reflect on all the other indexes which points to same reference, you need to add value you can see i am using [**spread syntax**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) for creating a copy of array

```
b.push([...a]);
```

```js
var a = [0,1];
var b = [];
b.push(a);
b.push([...a]);
b[0][0]=5;
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

By calling `b.push(a)` twice you are assigning the same array `a` to the first and second index of `b`. Therefore if you edit elements of `a` then it will be reflected for all references of the same instance.

You can perform a deep copy of `a` to prevent this.

E.g.,

```
b.push(a.slice());
b.push(a.slice());
```